# How to change mapkit map view zoom-level with a slider?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

So I have a map view(mapkit based) and a slider in my storyboard. As the user slides, map zooms in or out based on their action. How do I implement that? I think that might have something to do with longitudeDelta and latitudeDelta.

Please help me.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ConfigureViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapkitView: MKMapView!
    @IBOutlet weak var travelRadius: UILabel!
    @IBAction func button(sender: AnyObject) {


    }

    @IBAction func sliderChanged(sender: AnyObject) {
        let sliderValue = lrintf(sender.value)
        travelRadius.text = "\(sliderValue) mi."
        let delta = Double(self.sliderChanged(sender.value))
        var currentRegion = self.mapkitView.region

        currentRegion.span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: delta, longitudeDelta: delta)
        self.mapkitView.region = currentRegion

    }




    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()


    @IBOutlet weak var mapKitView: MKMapView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        self.mapKitView.showsUserLocation = true




        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {


        let location = locations.last

        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location!.coordinate.longitude)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 1.5,
            longitudeDelta: 1.5))


        self.mapKitView.setRegion(region, animated: false)

        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }
    func  locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError)
    {
        print ("Errors:" + error.localizedDescription)
    }






}
```

[Screenshot of my storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSAoI.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the zoom via the `region` property of the `mapView`. It defines both the center point of the map and the span (i.e. zoom level)

---

#### Edit

Do yourself a favor and define a separate `IBOutlet` for the slider. It turns out that your slider is measured in miles, but the span is measured in degrees latitude and longitude. How long 1 degree of latitude/longitude is in terms of miles vary depend on your location on Earth. Wikipedia has some discussion on [latitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latitude#Length_of_a_degree_of_latitude) and [longitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitude#Length_of_a_degree_of_longitude). *Assuming you are on the equator*, the conversion is 69 miles per degree of both.

(Remember to connect the outlets)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    @IBOutlet weak var slider: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet weak var travelRadius: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var currentLocationLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        sliderChanged(self) // Set the correct zoom according to the slider initial value
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func sliderChanged(sender: AnyObject) {
        let miles = Double(self.slider.value)
        let delta = miles / 69.0

        var currentRegion = self.mapView.region
        currentRegion.span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: delta, longitudeDelta: delta)
        self.mapView.region = currentRegion

        travelRadius.text = "\(Int(round(miles))) miles"

        let (lat, long) = (currentRegion.center.latitude, currentRegion.center.longitude)
        currentLocationLabel.text = "Current location: \(lat), \(long))"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think that's a correct direction to solve this problem. But my app crushes in the simulator, and I got a thread on the line     let delta = Double(self.changeView(sender.value)) called Exc_Bad_Access(code=1, address=0x198)

Comment: What's `self.changeView`?

Comment: Oh, sorry, it's "self.sliderChanged". And one thing I failed to mention, it's that, if you checkout my screenshot of my storyboard, this slider also controls a label text, you know, as user slides, they will see the number increased. I will update my code in the question field. Oh, one more thing, I want to display user's current location in the center too.

Comment: "Current location" as in GPS coordinates or city name, like "Chicago, Illinois, USA"?

Comment: GPS coordinates, you see the function location manager at the button, that's what I do originality to  center user's location on the map.

Comment: Critical part is my app crashes when I slide now.

Comment: Thank you, greatly appreciated. Life saver

Comment: Hi! You were being really helpful at this question. And I kinda want to ask your help for this question, which I think it's a little challenge. I'm a beginner, I tried so many times, "It just won't work". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37982076/app-crashes-at-segue-breakpoint-occurs-at-prepareforsegue