# iOS App crashes at segue (breakpoint occurs at func prepareForSegue)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7, segue

**Update: I figuire out, it's very hard to debug just by reading through the code, especially in a situation like this,https://www.dropbox.com/s/ty3clsvgednzevj/LoaferMap%20for%20iPhone%20copy%202.zip?dl=0, so I upload my project to dropbox if you want to reproduce the bug.**
**I deleted destination.delete(self), now it's gone. But the app still crashes. I realized the problem in SliderViewController maybe the code I wrote is simply unexcuteable. I'm a beginner, new to swift programming language. Your help means a lot to me.**

> If you download my project, and look at it. My goal is actually pretty straightforward, you use a slider to select a travel radius, and there are long lines of code generates a random location based on my current location. And finally pass that code to destinationViewController, to display a flyover animation based on the new generated location. But right now I think everything is set up correctly, but the app still crushes.

My app crashes when I'm about to transition form one view to the next.

```
     override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
         if (segue.identifier == "sendLocationdata") {
             let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! DestinationViewController
```

> Thread 1, Breakpoint 1.1

```
   destination.latitude = latitude
   destination.longitude = longitude
          }
```

More source code in the VC, and next VC, you can check another question I asked [How to Pass Data from View Controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37980480/how-to-pass-data-from-view-controllers/37980641?noredirect=1#comment63408998_37980641).

Comment: What is the destination.delete(self) call for?

Comment: It's hard to tell from what you've posted. Can you add a breakpoint at `if (segue.identifier == "sendLocationdata") {` and then run `po segue.identifier` to make sure you're getting the right segue

Also, as Sam suggested that `destination.delete(self)` looks scary

Comment: Please provide the entire code snippet in this question instead of giving the link to another question. Also if you're getting a log in console when the crash happens, please post that as well. As others said I also suspect destination.delete(self) is the culprit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
segue.destinationViewController
```

is not destinationViewController 
this class is a UINavigationController

you have to set latitude and longitude to UINavigationController's rootViewController

please edit like this

[image]